# JavasScript code not working

Tags: javascript

I am about to do an image slider and the javascript is not working in the code.
I embedded it in an external javascript file and also the internal file that is working with but it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <style> 
    .mySlides {display:none}

    /* Slideshow container */
     .slideshow-container {
      max-width: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
     }

    /* Next & previous buttons */
     .prev, .next {
     cursor: pointer;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     width: auto;
     padding: 16px;
     margin-top: -22px;
     color: white;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 18px;
     transition: 0.6s ease;
     border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    }

    /* Position the "next button" to the right */
    .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through 
    */
     .prev:hover, .next:hover {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     }

     /* Caption text */
    .text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    }

    /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
   .numbertext {
   color: #f2f2f2;
   font-size: 12px;
   padding: 8px 12px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   }

  /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
   .dot {
   cursor:pointer;
   height: 13px;
   width: 13px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
    }

    .active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
   }

   /* Fading animation */
   .fade {
   -webkit-animation-name: fade;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
    to {opacity: 1}
    }

    @keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4} 
     to {opacity: 1}
     }

   /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
   @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
   } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="slideshow-container">
   <div class="mySlides fade">
   <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
   <img src="resources/img_03.jpg" style="width:100%">
   <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
   </div>

   <div class="mySlides fade">
   <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
   <img src="resources/img_01.jpg" style="width:100%">
   <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
     <img src="resources/img_02.jpg" style="width:100%">
     <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

   </div>
   <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
   </div>
   </section>
   <script>
     var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
     showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

   function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

   function showSlides(n) {
   var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
   dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
   }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  }
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I don't know how to make the javascript have an effect on the image slider.

Comment: Can you provide full code snippet?

Comment: What's all that CSS for? You really expect people to read that to debug your javascript for you?

Comment: i just want to know how to place th javascript correctly

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine.

Add the script before body closing tag()

Answer (score -2):

what is the type you have save the file. Save it as js file